# How do I get all points in an ellipse knowing one point and the two focal.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have to develop an algorithm that return all the points of a ellipse knowing one point and the two focal points.
That's what I already have to work with:

> $P(x, y)$
>
> $F_1(x',y')$
>
> $F_2(x'',y'')$

Is it possibly? If so, how to do it?

Sorry if I miss something, I'm not really much of a mathematician.

Comment: @EthanBolker You're correct.  I removed my erroneous post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipse in question consists of all the points such that the sum of the distances from the foci is constant. You know the foci, and can easily compute the constant from the known point on the ellipse.

Then you have an equation in the coordinates $(x,y)$ of the general point on the ellipse.

Whether that counts as an algorithm "returning all the points" depends on the use you want to make of the information. You can use it to generate points, or to test if a point is on the ellipse.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I didn't see it. Sorry for make you lose your time.

Comment: Of course not. An equation is _not_  an algorithm. Algorithm is a specific method of obtaining a desired result, whilst an equation is a just another way to _describe_ the result, not necessarily allowing to actually _find_ it (compare the equation $x^11 +4x = -8$; it is a kind of description of some real value, which satisfies it – but it does not describe a way to **find** that value).

Comment: @SilasSales You're welcome. The time I spent wasn't wasted. It's easy not to see things that are obvious once you see them. Mathematicians do that often.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. It's **impossible**.

Algorithm, by definition, must perform **finite** number of steps, so it can produce only finite set of output data. And an ellipse contains **infintely** (even worse: **uncountably** infinitely!) many points.

Hence **no algorithm** can find **all** points of an ellipse.

Comment: I feel like the question is not asking for the coordinates of all the points in an ellipse, but an equation which describes the ellipse, which is possible.

Comment: I see your point, you are by all means technically right, but I only need a finite number of points to represent a graphic ellipse on a screen, and that is what I am after in the end, I just scape to mention this on my question. Thank you.

Comment: So possibly you should ask about _'an algorithm to find a (finite!) set of nodes of a square network (pixels) approximating an ellipse'_? Or you can ask for a method to describe the ellipse with an equation first, and then for an algorithm to draw an approximation of a curve given by the equation...

Comment: @CiaPan This is a correct answer to a literal reading of the question. But the OP is not a mathematician or a logician so it makes sense to try to figure out what he _really_ might mean or need.

Comment: @EthanBolker I tried. See my previous comment.